# If I use react-bootstrap, do I need to reference it in the App.html?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I want to know, if I use react-bootstrap, do I need to reference it in the App.html?
Like this,

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Besides,
the Bootstrap version is 4.5.0.
So would Bootstrap4 don't support the `import` style?
Because the `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` didn't take effect in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `import` statement to **`index.js`** file. Check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/webpack/#importing-compiled-css)

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Hi, Prathap! Thanks for your guide. I tried the two lines, but none of them took effect. And I am developing in a Electron environment, which I don't know whether have some relationship with this issue.

Comment: Is adding `<link>` tag in `App.html` working for you (As posted in your question)? Are you asking if this is the right way of adding `bootstrap`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, either we can use `import` as suggested in answer or use direct [cdn link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#css) in `index.html` (`App.html` in your case). Both are correct approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your guide. I guess this might be due to the usage of `.tsx` in my code. So the Bootstrap cannot be loaded using `import`.

Comment: I want know, as for `react-bootstrap` or `reactstrap`, which one do you prefer?

Comment: I used to sail with the wind in case of ambiguity. [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) is my choice since it has more weekly downloads than [reactstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactstrap).